# How to make vindicator open doors

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a minecraft map where a Vindicator will chase you.

The problem is the vindicator can't open doors, and the map will be ugly if i place pressure plates in every door.

Comment: Are you open to a commands system that opens doors when vindicator is nearby?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a perfect fit for [sculk sensors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sculk_Sensor), but they won't be available until 1.17 is released.

Without them, there are still a few options:

- Pressure plates, which you already said would look ugly.
- [Tripwire hooks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tripwire_Hook), probably uglier unless you can hide them in the walls or with some kind of decoration.
- [Redstone ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Ore) glows for a while when you step on it, and an observer would be able to detect the change, both when it starts glowing and again when it stops. It would look uglier than pressure plates... however, you can cover it with carpets and it still works¹, making it the least intrusive option of them.

That's the only options I can think of, at least in Bedrock, survival mode. In Java edition, you could also build a much more difficult, but completely hidden, pufferfish detector. But as usual, those [don't work in Bedrock edition](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/boiyoq/do_pufferfish_detectors_work_on_bedrock/).

<sub>1: Tested on Bedrock edition 1.16.210.</sub>